# Can I use GetConfigValue() function from ASPX Page?

Tags: dxa, configuration, dxa-net

For some business reason both ASPX & MVC views are co-existing in the MVC DXA application. Is there any way get site confuguration values calling the GetConfigValue function ( Namespace - Sdl.Web.Common.Configuration Class - Localization) from ASPX code behind?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried it yet for aspx code behind but you should be able to use WebRequestContext.Localization.GetConfigValue("YourConfig"). Please update here if you face any error in using that?

Comment: Mukesh, That's not working, error -Request is not available in this context